# Devdemon forms not working when there is a 301 redirect

Tags: devdemon, devdemon-forms

If I have the following in my .htaccess

```
    RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !^www\.domain\.com$
    RewriteRule (.*) http://www.domain.com/$1 [R=301,L]
```

When I go to submit a form on the website, forms just essentially refreshes the page. There is nothing in the database and no email is received. If I comment out those two lines, then it will work fine. In the general configuration it is set to http://www.domain.com. I'm also submitting the form with the www. in the address bar.

EE 2.6.1
Forms 3.3.5

Comment: If you inspect the form source code, what domain is the `action` set to?

Comment: The action is set to domain.com, not www.domain.com. Where is it pulling this from? I'm on my phone.

Answer (score 1):

Thanks Derek, for pointing that out.

I edited system/expressionengine/config/config.php and changed

```
$config['base_url'] = "http://domain.com";
```

to

```
$config['base_url'] = "http://www.domain.com";
```

Then added the Rewrite back to my .htaccess

```
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !^www\.domain\.com$
RewriteRule (.*) http://www.domain.com/$1 [R=301,L]
```

After doing this, I was able to successfully submit the form.